# Weird behavior of https clients on 16.04 and 18.04, ssl related

Tags: ssl

I have two ubuntu boxes, let's say box A (16.04) and box B(18.04). They access internet in a significantly different way, but typically I use VPS C(16.04) as a proxy (tinyproxy)

There is a site, allowing for optional ssl protection. I can open it without SSL (http:// prefix) from both machines in any way imaginable. However, when I use SSL (https:// prefix) I can open it from box B both **with and without proxy** C involved, but cannot open from box A **with or without proxy**. There is NO error message, the connection simply times out on "waiting for...". Similar behaviour was found for Chromium and wget.

The problem occurs with at least one site, but most are unaffected.

WTF?

How can I diagnose the problem further?

edit: box A has IPv4 address and IS behind a firewall that, for example, blocks incoming connections on SSH default port. Box B doesn't have direct IP address and is behind two levels of NAT. However, **both A and B connect to C (and talk to C) via an encripted openVPN tunnel which is not blocked or inspected.**

The problem clearly is in box A, it cannot be anywhere else. But I never configured any firewals on it, so if there is anything blocking connection, I didn't install it or at the very least I do not remember installing it.

Comment: My guess is that there is some DPI product (firewall, IDS, IPS..) which restricts what sites and with protocols A can access. It does not matter much for this if A is accessing the https site through a proxy C or directly: the blocking is done before it reaches either the final server (direct access) or the proxy C. The connection to the proxy can be inspected too since it is not encrypted.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich see update.

Comment: If the OpenVPN tunnel actually starts at box A and ends at box C and if the traffic is actually going through this VPN (have you verified this?) then it cannot be something in the middle. I recommend to do a packet capture and compare the traffic from A and B.